# Changing EACH buttons background images with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to EACH button separately to change its background images as the user rollovers it.

As I have it by the moment, they are changing but BOTH buttons at the same time and that it's not what I would like them to behave.

Please could you help me?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nb7LV/2/

Many thanks in advance!!! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `each()`. Just use `$(".button").hover()`

And use this in the callback:

```
$(this).children('.btn-left').eq(0).toggleClass('btn-left-hover');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script changes every button because you put all of the toggles under the `each()`, which means all toggles apply when any of them trigger the hover event.

But you don't even need JavaScript / jQuery. Just make the following change in your CSS and remove your jQuery:

```
.button:hover .btn-left{
    background:url(../images/btn-left-hover.png);
}

.button:hover .btn-middle{
    background:url(../images/btn-middle-hover.png);
}

.button:hover .btn-right{
    background:url(../images/btn-right-hover.png);
}
```

Alternatively, you can make the following edit to your script. This will only update the `span`s that are children of your hovered element.

```
$(this).find('.btn-left').toggleClass('btn-left-hover');
$(this).find('.btn-middle').toggleClass('btn-middle-hover');
$(this).find('.btn-right').toggleClass('btn-right-hover');
```

Comment: That won't work since there are three spans to each button. It will only change the span the mouse is over instead of all three.

Comment: Something more like `.button:hover .btn-left{ ... }` for all three would probably work, although I think it's better to use javascript for animation type things anyways isn't it?

Comment: No, when it's hover effects like this that CSS can cover, it's better practice to use CSS typically.

Comment: I see. I didn't know hover was cross browser except on `<a>` tag. How is that a fix though, it's slower code (ever so slightly) which does the same thing?

Comment: Is it slower? An elimination of scripting is "better" in as much as it reduces maintenance. `:hover` is covered by CSS for a reason. And `:hover` is standard CSS, so it is cross browser, but in IE6 it only works on the anchor tag. Of course, [even Microsoft has depreciated IE6](http://ie6countdown.com/). I would think `:hover` is faster than JavaScript because the browser knows the CSS class will change on hover the entire time; with the jQuery method, the browser doesn't know until it is time to change. For a well-programmed browser, it seems like CSS would then be faster.

Comment: No, I didn't say the css is slower. The Javascript you provided is slower than what I posted

Comment: That's good to know btw, I guess it's been to long wince I learnt about first learnt not to use the `:hover` selector and now it's just become habit for me to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, your jQuery is better than my jQuery change for multiple reasons, but I think the `:hover` selector is the best route.

Comment: Many thanks!!! Both of your unswers helped me!! =D But unfurnatelly my client wanted this for IE6 included so that was the reason I was using jquery =( (yeah, I know...I know!! but he said 12% of his clients are STILL using IE6). So well....

Comment: Since you are new to Stack Overflow, you might not realize this: assuming @PaulPRO's answer helped you, you should click the checkmark next to it to mark it as *the* answer to your question.

Comment: @PaulPRO: Just for your info (if that's what you were talking about with "The Javascript you provided is slower"), `$('.btn-left', this)` maps to `$(this).find('.btn-left')`. They are "identical".

Answer (score 0):

Just specify that the context is `this` for each of your selectors:

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
    $('.btn-left', this).toggleClass('btn-left-hover');
    $('.btn-middle', this).toggleClass('btn-middle-hover');
    $('.btn-right', this).toggleClass('btn-right-hover');
});
```

I also removed the `.each()` since that's unnecessary (hover will be applied to each matching element anyways).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/Nb7LV/7/)